Sort function to achieve custom difference along with multiple columns
Trying to achieve custom sort as below:
// 1. sort by 'value' column, here 'a' (first object) and b (second object) has difference equals to 4.5 or less then 4.5 then,
// consider equal values (even though it's 12.12 and 13.22) 
// then 2. sort by 'altValue' column (as equal value found on 'value' column) and then,
// 3. sort by 'name' column (as equal value found on 'altValue').
const validSortEqualityDiffence = 4.5;
const inputArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'ABC INC.', value: 12.12, altValue: 22.22 },
  { id: 2, name: 'DBC INC.', value: 13.22, altValue: 23.32 },
  { id: 3, name: 'DBC INC.', value: 15.22, altValue: 25.42 },
  { id: 4, name: 'CBC INC.', value: 12.22, altValue: 22.32 },
  { id: 5, name: 'CBC INC.', value: 16.22, altValue: 26.32 },
  { id: 6, name: 'QBC INC.', value: 13.52, altValue: 23.72 },
  { id: 7, name: 'QBC INC.', value: 11.02, altValue: 21.92 },
];

/* below code error out as unable to find 'b' value here */
_.orderBy(
  inputArray,
  (a, b) => {
    console.log('a,b', a, b); // b is undfined

    if (Math.abs(a.value - b.value) <= validSortEqualityDiffence) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (a.value < b.value) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  },
  (a, b) => {
    console.log('a,b', a, b); // b is undfined

    if (Math.abs(a.altValue - b.altValue) <= validSortEqualityDiffence) {
      return 0;
    }
    if (a.altValue < b.altValue) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  },
  'name'
  );

Here, unable to get 'b' object.
Is there any alternate way using Array.sort or other lodash method that can help to achieve, sort with custom difference and consider multiple order by columns.
Thank You

Why not use the built in Array.sort() method in javascript? It works as you would expect where a function is provided which accepts a and b and sorts according to your function.

I can't find _.orderBy(). Is that supposed to be _.sortBy()?

It is orderBy, https://lodash.com/docs/#orderBy . In sortBy as well, can't find it.

But _.sortBy() doesn't take a comparison function. Its second argument is a function that extracts the key from the object, then it uses < to compare the keys.

lodash != underscore.js

If use Array.Sort(), here needs, multiple columns order by.

lodash _.orderBy() also takes an "iteratee" parameter, not comparison functions.

It supports comparison function. created here for quick, https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-k1iciq?file=index.js

No it doesn't. That's why you're getting undefined for b, because it only passes one element, and it's supposed to return the key from that.

It doesn't support 'b'. that's where looking resolution.

Lodash _.orderBy() and Underscore.js _.sortBy() don't take comparison functions, they take an iteratee argument, which extracts the key from each element. b is undefined because only one element is passed to the function at a time.
Use the built-in sort() method, and put the secondary ordering  in place of the first return 0; statement, and the tertiary ordering in place of the second return 0;.


const validSortEqualityDiffence = 4.5;

inputArray.sort(
  (a, b) => {
    if (Math.abs(a.value - b.value) <= validSortEqualityDiffence) {
      if (Math.abs(a.altValue - b.altValue) <= validSortEqualityDiffence) {
        return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
      }
      if (a.altValue < b.altValue) {
        return -1;
      }
      return 1;
    }
    if (a.value < b.value) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  });

console.log(inputArray);
<script>
const inputArray = [
  { id: 1, name: 'ABC INC.', value: 12.12, altValue: 22.22 },
  { id: 2, name: 'DBC INC.', value: 13.22, altValue: 23.32 },
  { id: 3, name: 'DBC INC.', value: 15.22, altValue: 25.42 },
  { id: 4, name: 'CBC INC.', value: 12.22, altValue: 22.32 },
  { id: 5, name: 'CBC INC.', value: 16.22, altValue: 26.32 },
  { id: 6, name: 'QBC INC.', value: 13.52, altValue: 23.72 },
  { id: 7, name: 'QBC INC.', value: 11.02, altValue: 21.92 },
];
</script>




Thank You. So for third column name , would fall under if (Math.abs(a.altValue - b.altValue) <= validSortEqualityDiffence) {         return 0;       }

Sorry, missed that part. I added return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
